# Generating n amount new rows on a pandas dataframe based off values given in other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So, I have the following sample dataframe (included only one row for clarity/simplicity):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'base_number': [2],
                   'std_dev': [1]})
df['amount_needed'] = 5
df['upper_bound'] = df['base_number'] + df['std_dev']
df['lower_bound'] = df['base_number'] - df['std_dev']
```

For each given rows, I would like to generate the amount of rows such that the total amount per row is the number given by `df['amount_needed']` (so 5, in this example). I would like those 5 new rows to be spread across a spectrum given by `df['upper_bound']` and `df['lower_bound']`. So for the example above, I would like the following result as an output:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'base_number': [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]})
```

Of course, this process will be done for all rows in a much larger dataframe, with many other columns which aren't relevant to this particular issue, which is why I'm trying to find a way to automate this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using jsmart's contribution and working on it to generate a new dataframe, conserving original id's in order to merge the other columns from the old one onto this new one according to id as needed (whole process shown below):

```
amount_needed = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({'base_number': [2, 4, 8, 0],

                   'std_dev': [1, 2, 3, 0]})
df['amount_needed'] = amount_needed
df['upper_bound'] = df['base_number'] + df['std_dev']
df['lower_bound'] = df['base_number'] - df['std_dev']

s1 = pd.Series([],dtype = int)
for row in df.itertuples():
    arr = np.linspace(row.lower_bound, 
                      row.upper_bound, 
                      row.amount_needed)
    s = pd.Series(arr).rename('base_number')
    s1 = pd.concat([s1, s])
  
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'base_number': s1})

ids_og = list(range(1, len(df) + 1))
ids_og = [ids_og] * amount_needed
ids_og = sorted(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(ids_og)))

df_new['id'] = ids_og
```

Answer (score 0):

One row of `df` will create one series (or one data frame).  Here's one way to iterate over `df` and create the series with the values you specified:

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    arr = np.linspace(row.lower_bound, 
                      row.upper_bound, 
                      row.amount_needed)
    s = pd.Series(arr).rename('base_number')
    
print(s)

0    1.0
1    1.5
2    2.0
3    2.5
4    3.0
Name: base_number, dtype: float64
```